# How do I switch to Unicode entry mode?

Tags: 10.10, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to switch into Unicode entry mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, but after I hit this combination nothing happens. I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. Do I need to enable this mode anywhere? Or maybe it works only in certain places? I use default USA layout.

Comment: What application are you trying it in?

Comment: @Chipaca I tried in several: Firefox. Terminal, gedit... none of them works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature works in all gtk+-based applications when they use the default gtk+ input method. For example, all GNOME applications, OpenOffice.org and Firefox.

However, if you have enabled IBus in order to write complex scripts, then you lose the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> facility. You would need to disable IBus and return bug to the gtk+ input method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a GNOME feature, and it should work for all GNOME applications.

Comment: I see, seems that something is broken my OS...

Answer (score 0):

You get very little feedback when you do this, but, when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> you should get an underlined u. You then enter the unicode codepoint, followed by space or enter; until you hit space or enter you'll only see the underlined u followed by the codepoint as you entered it; when you hit space or enter the whole thing is replaced by the unicode character.